# Can't upload bigger file using Wordpress Docker and Nginx with configured Certbot

Tags: nginx, docker, wordpress

I configured Wordpress on Docker Image:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    volumes:
      - 'db_data:/var/lib/mysql'
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
  wordpress:
    image: 'wordpress:latest'
    ports:
      - 80
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: 'db:3306'
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
 
volumes:
  db_data: null
```

and I changed max_execution to 300, upload_max_filesize to 500 time and memory_limit to 256MB correctly inside Wordpress container settings file. I checked it in php_info and looks ok.

But when I try to upload file 123MB it stopping around 30 seconds in middle always. Diffrent % usually. Im using All-In-One Migration Plugin but using others also stopping in middle.

Im using nginx as reverse proxy with configured CertBot. Im doing everything using Portainer. Im using ARM proccessor.

I dont see any logs error or message.

What I need to do to make uploading working good?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was problem with nginx configuration. I was think that if nginx is only used as reverse proxy, then it have not too much to talk but it was not true.

Solution was add this to configuration of my domain inside /etc/nginx/conf.d/CONFIGFILE.conf inside location {}

```
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_send_timeout 300;
client_max_body_size 500M;
```